# Calling unknown method: yii2mod\cms\controllers\CmsController::setInstance()

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-extension

I don't understand why this error occur.

get error on call a cms 
`http://localhost/yii-cms/web/cms`

Calling unknown method: `yii2mod\cms\controllers\CmsController::setInstance()`

i am try to use of `yii2-cms`

cmsController

```
   <?php

namespace yii2mod\cms\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii2mod\cms\models\CmsModel;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii2mod\cms\models\search\CmsModelSearch;
use yii2mod\editable\EditableAction;
use yii2mod\toggle\actions\ToggleAction;

/**
 * Class CmsController
 * @package yii2mod\cms\controllers
 */
class CmsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @var string view path
     */
    public $viewPath = '@vendor/yii2mod/yii2-cms/views/cms/';

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'index' => ['get'],
                    'create' => ['get', 'post'],
                    'update' => ['get', 'post'],
                    'delete' => ['post']
                ],
            ]
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'edit-page' => [
                'class' => EditableAction::className(),
                'modelClass' => CmsModel::className(),
                'forceCreate' => false
            ],
            'toggle' => [
                'class' => ToggleAction::className(),
                'modelClass' => CmsModel::className(),
            ]
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Lists all CmsModel models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new CmsModelSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render($this->viewPath . 'index', [
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'searchModel' => $searchModel
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new CmsModel model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new CmsModel();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', Yii::t('yii2mod.cms', 'Page has been created.'));
            return $this->redirect(['index']);
        }

        return $this->render($this->viewPath . 'create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing CmsModel model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     *
     * @param integer $id
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', Yii::t('yii2mod.cms', 'Page has been updated.'));
            return $this->redirect(['index']);
        }
        return $this->render($this->viewPath . 'update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing CmsModel model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     *
     * @param integer $id
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', Yii::t('yii2mod.cms', 'Page has been deleted.'));
        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    /**
     * Finds the CmsModel model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     *
     * @param integer $id
     *
     * @return CmsModel the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = CmsModel::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException(Yii::t('yii2mod.cms', 'The requested page does not exist.'));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: show your related controller code .. please

Comment: @scaisEdge i have updated

Comment: `setInstance()` is a method from the `yii\base\Module` class. Did you correctly setup your config file ? Did you define a module somewhere ?

Comment: Show your error stack trace would help.

Comment: yes i have defined module in config file @slayvin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have following [yii2-cms](https://github.com/yii2mod/yii2-cms) and it's work great

**set instance** error occur due to they can not find out given class and that's possible due to miss configuration.

**follow Configuration Link** https://github.com/yii2mod/yii2-cms#configuration

1) To use this extension first you need to configure the comments extension, after that you have to configure the main config in your application:

```
'modules' => [
        'admin' => [
            'controllerMap' => [
                'cms' => 'yii2mod\cms\controllers\CmsController'
                // You can set your template files
                // 'layout' => '@app/modules/backend/views/layouts/main',
                // 'viewPath' => '@app/modules/backend/views/cms/',
            ],
        ],
    ],

You can then access to management section through the following URL:

http://localhost/path/to/index.php?r=admin/cms/index
```

2) Add new Rule class to the urlManager array in your application configuration by the following code:

```
 'components' => [
        'urlManager' => [
            'rules' => [
                ['class' => 'yii2mod\cms\components\PageUrlRule'],
            ]
        ],
    ],
```

3) Add to SiteController (or configure via $route param in urlManager):

```
/**
 * @return array
 */
public function actions()
{
    return [
        'page' => [
            'class' => 'yii2mod\cms\actions\PageAction',
            // You can set your template files
            'view' => '@app/views/site/page'
        ],
    ];
}
And now you can create your own pages via the admin panel, and access them via the url of each page.
```

Comment: same answer but you have give me reason when this kind of error arrived.thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes error is solved by following proper Configuration STEP.

Error is occur due to miss configure second step

2) Add new Rule class to the urlManager array in your application configuration by the following code:

```
'components' => [
        'urlManager' => [
            'rules' => [
                ['class' => 'yii2mod\cms\components\PageUrlRule'],
            ]
        ],
    ],
```

Full Configuration you need to did :

1) To use this extension first you need to configure the comments extension, after that you have to configure the main config in your application:

```
'modules' => [
        'admin' => [
            'controllerMap' => [
                'cms' => 'yii2mod\cms\controllers\CmsController'
                // You can set your template files
                // 'layout' => '@app/modules/backend/views/layouts/main',
                // 'viewPath' => '@app/modules/backend/views/cms/',
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

You can then access to management section through the following URL:

http://localhost/path/to/index.php?r=admin/cms/index
2) Add new Rule class to the urlManager array in your application configuration by the following code:

```
'components' => [
        'urlManager' => [
            'rules' => [
                ['class' => 'yii2mod\cms\components\PageUrlRule'],
            ]
        ],
    ],
```

3) Add to SiteController (or configure via $route param in urlManager):

```
 /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'page' => [
                'class' => 'yii2mod\cms\actions\PageAction',
                // You can set your template files
                'view' => '@app/views/site/page'
            ],
        ];
    }
```

And now you can create your own pages via the admin panel, and access them via the url of each page.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using the cms extension in your site component as-is.

In your `web.php` file, add this:

`'components' => [
    ...
    'i18n' => [
          'translations' => [
              '*' => [
                  'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                  'basePath' => '@app/messages'
                  'sourceLanguage' => 'en',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ]
    ...,
    'controllerMap': => [
        'cms' => 'yii2mod\cms\controllers\CmsController'
    ],`

NOTE: You should exclude the path about configuring it as a component in the admin module since you're not using it anyway.

If you were using it in a module, then the steps documented in the README is just fine for you.